# Watson Assistant and node-red

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, node-red, watson-assistant

I am trying to use node-red to connect to my Watson chatbot using the Watson assistant v2 node. For some reason, I keep getting forbidden returns and It doesn't seem to connect properly? Has anyone managed to successfully connect to a Watson service using Node-red?

[image: Node-red Flow]

I am not sure the correct combination of API key or ID to connect to the correct service

Comment: You probably want more than a "yes" as answer. Add more details on your setup and any specific question

Comment: @data_henrik Post has now been edited, hopefully that helps

Answer (score 0):

In the Watson Assistant UI go to the **Assistant** you want to use, then to the **Settings** section. The Assistant ID and URL are shown, then in the **Service credentials** section the API key.

Enter them in the configuration of your node.

[image]

Comment: Even after inputting this I still receive the "Resource not found " Error

Comment: please see above, any assistance is appreciated @data_henrik

Answer (score 0):

For those who came late for this question:
To use IBM watson node-red nodes

1. search for the service in [IBM cloud](https://cloud.ibm.com/).
2. Create the service.
3. Get the credentials.
4. Go to node-red editor and paste the credentials (API key + URL)